# Access to XMLHttpRequest at .... from origin ... has been blocked by CORS policy (Angular to Core web api)

Tags: angular, cors, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm in Visual Studio 2022, with two projects: one Angular and one WebAPI. I am getting the CORS error:
[image]

I hope someone can shed some light on the issue, the relevant code is as follows.

For the WebAPI project, this is the code for launchSettings.json:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://json.schemastore.org/launchsettings.json",
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": true,
    "anonymousAuthentication": false,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:58240",
      "sslPort": 44321
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "api/startup",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I should add that launchUrl shows the startup page. For Program.cs:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
string _corsPolicy = "defaultPolicy";

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddCors( options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy( 
        _corsPolicy, 
        policyBuilder => {policyBuilder.WithOrigins("https://localhost:7098")
                                       .AllowAnyMethod()
                                       .AllowAnyHeader();});});

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
builder.Services.AddMvc( options =>
{
    var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
        .Build();
    options.Filters.Add( new AuthorizeFilter( policy ) );
});

builder.Services.AddControllers();
var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseCors(_corsPolicy);
app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => { endpoints.MapControllers().RequireCors( _corsPolicy ); });
app.Run();
```

You can see I've added *https://localhost:7098* for WithOrigins, and I have the following component code in the Angular project (I added the last two methods to the boilerplate code provided by VS), a button click calls clickEvent:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-nav-menu',
  templateUrl: './nav-menu.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./nav-menu.component.css']
})
export class NavMenuComponent {
  isExpanded = false;

  collapse() {
    this.isExpanded = false;
  }

  toggle() {
    this.isExpanded = !this.isExpanded;
  }

  constructor(private readonly httpClient: HttpClient) {}

  clickEvent() {
    this.headsUp().subscribe(data => {});
  };

  headsUp(): Observable<any> {
    return this.httpClient.get<any>(`https://localhost:44321/api/headsup/`);
  };

}
```

Finally, this is my web api code:

```
    [ApiController]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class HeadsupController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly ILogger<HeadsupController> _logger;

        public HeadsupController(ILogger<HeadsupController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public async Task<string> Get()
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("The Ops API Service has started.");
            return await Task.Run(() => "Made it!");
        }
    }
```

I am puzzled as to why I am getting the CORS error, everything seems in order. Can anyone assist?

Answer (score 0):

From [CORS preflight request](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/cors-module/cors-module-configuration-reference#cors-preflight-request), you can find following information:

A CORS preflight request is used to determine whether the resource being requested is set to be shared across origins by the server. The OPTIONS requests are always anonymous, server would not correctly respond to the preflight request if anonymous authentification is not enabled.
[image]

To fix this issue, if you run the App(s) on local for testing purpose with CORS, you can try to enable anonymous authentification.
So try to set  `"anonymousAuthentication": true,` in your WebAPI  launchSettings.json.

result:

[image]

Comment: Qing, thank you for the reply. If I set anonymousAuthentication to true and keep windowsAuthentication true, I get a 401 error. If anon is true and windows is false, I get error 'InvalidOperationException: No authenticationScheme was specified, and there was no DefaultChallengeScheme found.'  The link you provided is interesting and I will read it.

Comment: The error 'InvalidOperationException: No authenticationScheme was specified, and there was no DefaultChallengeScheme found.' is because you have add `builder.Services.AddAuthentication(IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);` , try  to remove it.